# Get all names from wikipedia-site?

Tags: python, web-scraping, wikipedia, pywikibot

i try to extract all names from this site -

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Masculine_given_names

(and i want to have all names which are listed on this site and the following pages - but also the subcategories which are listed at the top like Afghan masculine given names, African masculine given names, etc.)

I tried this with the following code:

```
import pywikibot
from pywikibot import pagegenerators
site = pywikibot.Site()
cat = pywikibot.Category(site,'Category:Masculine_given_names')
gen = pagegenerators.CategorizedPageGenerator(cat)
for idx,page in enumerate(gen):
  text = page.text
  print(idx)
  print(text)
```

Which generally works fine and gave me at least the detail-page of a single name page. But how can i get all the names / from all the subpages on this site but also from the subcategories?

Comment: [Petscan query](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?labels_yes=&cb_labels_any_l=1&ns%5B0%5D=1&project=wikipedia&language=en&categories=Masculine%20given%20names%7C3&cb_labels_yes_l=1&since_rev0=&edits%5Bbots%5D=both&edits%5Bflagged%5D=both&search_max_results=500&edits%5Banons%5D=both&cb_labels_no_l=1&interface_language=en&&doit=) might be useful and easier to get a list of all the names including the subcategories.  I have used depth of 3 for subcategories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to find subcategories and subpages on wikipedia using pywikibot?**

This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71023854/how-to-find-subcategories-and-subpages-on-wikipedia-using-pywikibot) using `Category` methods but you can also use pagegenerators `CategorizedPageGenerator` function. All you need is setting the recurse option:

```
  >>> gen = pagegenerators.CategorizedPageGenerator(cat, recurse=True)
```

Refer the [documentation](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.html?highlight=categorizedpagegenerator#pywikibot.pagegenerators.CategorizedPageGenerator) for it. You may also include [pagegenerators options](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.html#generator-options) within your script in such a way decribed in this [example](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/installation.html#script-example) and call your script with `-catr` option:

```
  pwb.py <yourscript> -catr:Masculine_given_names
```