# How to find subcategories and subpages on wikipedia using pywikibot?

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, pywikibot

i would like to get all (87) subcategories and all pages (200) in the "Pages in category "Masculine given names"" section on this site:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Masculine_given_names

I tried it with the following code:

```
import pywikibot
site = pywikibot.Site("en", "wikipedia")
page = pywikibot.Page(site, 'Category:Masculine_given_names')
print(list(page.categories()))
```

But with that i only get the categories at the very bottom of the page.
How can i get the subcategoreis and (sub)-pages on this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How can i get the subcategories and (sub)-pages of a given category?**

First you have to use a `Category` class instead of a `Page` class. You have to create it quite similar:

```
  >>> import pywikibot
  >>> site = pywikibot.Site("en", "wikipedia")
  >>> cat = pywikibot.Category(site, 'Masculine_given_names')
```

A Category class has additional methods, refer the [documentation](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/stable/api_ref/pywikibot.html?highlight=category#pywikibot.Category) for further informations and the available parameters. The `categoryinfo` property for example gives a short overview about the category content:

```
  >>> cat.categoryinfo
  {'size': 1425, 'pages': 1336, 'files': 0, 'subcats': 89}
```

There are 1425 entries in this category, there are 1336 pages and 89 subcategories in this case.

To get all *subcategories* use `subcategories()` method:

```
  >>> gen = cat.subcategories()
```

Note, this is a generator. As shown below you will get all of them as found in `categoryinfo` above:

```
  >>> len(list(gen))
  89
```

To get all *pages* (articles) you have to use the `articles()` method, e.g.

```
  >>> gen = cat.subcategories()
```

Guess how many entries the corresponing list will have.

Finally there is a method to get all *members* of the category which includes pages, files and subcategories called `members()`:

```
  >>> gen = cat.members()
```

Comment: Can you get all nested sub-categories with this method? How do you deal with recursivity?